# How do you make minikube ssh work with kitty

Tags: linux, terminal, kubernetes, kitty

If you use `minikube ssh` with kitty backspace and other characters do not work properly.

The problem is that the terminfo is not copied across, however, it's not possible to do `kitty +kitten ssh` as suggested in the [kitty FAQ](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/faq.html#i-get-errors-about-the-terminal-being-unknown-or-opening-the-terminal-failing-when-sshing-into-a-different-computer) because `tic` is not installed on minikube and so fails with the following error:

`bash: line 58: tic: command not found`

How can you get kitty and minikube to play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this neatly in one line using `scp`, `minikube ip` and `minikube ssh-key` so long as `TERMINFO` is set correctly on your host machine.

```
scp -r -i $(minikube ssh-key) $TERMINFO docker@$(minikube ip):/home/docker/.terminfo/
```